# c++ having trouble with abstract class

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, class

I have this class that will help me with animated meshes.

```
class CAllocateHierarchy: public ID3DXAllocateHierarchy
{
public:
    STDMETHOD(CreateFrame)(THIS_ LPCTSTR Name, LPD3DXFRAME *ppNewFrame);
    STDMETHOD(CreateMeshContainer)(THIS_ LPCTSTR Name, LPD3DXMESHDATA pMeshData,
                            LPD3DXMATERIAL pMaterials, LPD3DXEFFECTINSTANCE pEffectInstances, DWORD NumMaterials, 
                            DWORD *pAdjacency, LPD3DXSKININFO pSkinInfo, 
                            LPD3DXMESHCONTAINER *ppNewMeshContainer);
    STDMETHOD(DestroyFrame)(THIS_ LPD3DXFRAME pFrameToFree);
    STDMETHOD(DestroyMeshContainer)(THIS_ LPD3DXMESHCONTAINER pMeshContainerBase);
    CAllocateHierarchy(CMyD3DApplication *pApp) :m_pApp(pApp) {}
public:
    CMyD3DApplication* m_pApp;
};
```

but when i try to intallizes a class like `CAllocateHierarchy allloc(this);` i will get error.  `16  IntelliSense: object of abstract class type "CAllocateHierarchy" is not allowed:    c:\users\owner\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\monopoly\monopoly\monopoly.cpp 186`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates that you didn't override all the abstract methods from the interface ID3DXAllocateHierarchy.

Looking through the arguments, I see that you forgot the "const" for several arguments to the CreateMeshContainer() method. As a result, the C++ compiler thinks this is a different method, and complains that the original CreateMeshContainer() is still abstract.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205621(v=VS.85).aspx

```
HRESULT CreateMeshContainer(
  [in]           LPCSTR Name,
  [in]           const D3DXMESHDATA *pMeshData,
  [in]           const D3DXMATERIAL *pMaterials,
  [in]           const D3DXEFFECTINSTANCE *pEffectInstances,
  [in]           DWORD NumMaterials,
  [in]           const DWORD *pAdjacency,
  [in]           LPD3DXSKININFO pSkinInfo,
  [out, retval]  LPD3DXMESHCONTAINER *ppNewMeshContainer
);
```

So the solution is: Add 'const' to several arguments (but see update below).

**Update**: You also are missing some '*' in your arguments. Apparently you have declared the CreateMeshContainer to take arguments by value, while it should be by const pointer. Copy-pasting the declaration from the msdn link and removing the [in] tags might be the fastest way to get a correct declaration.

**Suggestion**: Using a different compiler might help to generate more insightful error messages, as might setting the warning level as high as possible. Some compilers list the methods that are still abstract. Some compilers might warn that your CreateMeshContainer() is not overriding the virtual CreateMeshContainer() in the interface. Every suggestion what is wrong could be helpful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is correct, as I was about to post the same answer.

Comment: Now that I look closer, I also noticed some missing '*' in the arguments: instead of the expected "const D3DXMESHDATA *pMeshData", you declared a "LPD3DXMESHDATA pMeshData". So adding const is not enough. Try updating your declaration by pasting the arguments from the MSDN link I provided.

Comment: And it's not just pMeshData that is not correct. I just used it as an example.

Comment: well, im learning from tutoral probably it i out of date, how did yu learn about animated mesh in directx 9 c++? did you use any tutorials that you can give me?

Comment: @Ramiz Sorry, I don't know anything about directx 9. I just recognized the compiler message and googled for the interface definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass doesn't implement at least one of the pure virtual methods (marked `virtual whatever = 0`) of its base class. You must implement all such methods in order to instantiate your subclass.